# A question about *Lauren Series Decomposition*

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

The  function  $$f(z)={1\over{(z-1)(z-2)}}$$  is  to  be  expanded   in  *Laurent Series* centered  at  $0$  and  converging  in  the  annular  region  $\{1\lt |z| \lt 2\}$ .

**How the book does it :**

$$f(z)={1\over{(z-1)(z-2)}}\\={1\over {z-2}}-{1\over{z-1}}$$
Next,$${1\over{z-2}}=-{1\over 2}{1\over {1-{z/2}}}\\=-{1\over 2}\left(1+{z\over 2}+{z^2\over 4}+...\right)$$
and $${1\over {z-1}}={1\over z}\cdot{1\over{1-1/z}}\\={1\over z}+{1\over z^2}+{1\over z^3}+...$$

Thus  we  have  our  expansion . Done.

**The alternative I was  doing  :**

$$f(z)={1\over{(z-1)(z-2)}}\\={1\over {z-2}}-{1\over{z-1}}$$
 Next,
$${1\over{z-2}}={1\over z}\cdot {1\over {1-2/z}}\\={1\over z}\left( 1+{2\over z}+{4\over z^2}+{8\over z^3}+....\right)$$

and $${1\over {z-1}}=-{1\over {1-z}}\\=- \left(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+.... \right)$$

In  both  cases , we  expand  the  series  in  sum  of  two  series  where  one  of  them  is  in  positive  powers  of  $z$  and  the  other  is  in  negative  powers  of  $z$ . Are  both  of  them  correct  or  is  there  a  particular  reason   that  the  book  expands  it  the  way  it  did  $?$  Does  the  region  of  expansion  gets  to  decide  how  the  expansion  should  be  done  $?$

Thank you  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laurent expansion of a holomorphic function in an annulus is unique. So one of the answers must be wrong. In fact your expansion is wrong.

You use the fact that $$\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n.$$
But that holds only for $|r|<1$. In both your expansions you use this formula for an $r$ with $|r|>1$. ($|2/z|>1$ and $|z|>1$ in the annulus in question.)

Comment: I was  actually  expecting  that  mine  would  be  wrong  and  there  must  be  reason   for  doing  it  in  one  way. I  needed  the  explanation .  Thanks.

Comment: Since  the  region  is  $\{1\lt |z| \lt 2\}$  , we  have $|{1\over z}|\lt 1$  and  $\{  |{z\over 2}|\lt 1 \}$.  So  the  region  of  expansion  has  a  crucial  role in  deciding  how  the  expansion  is  done.  :)